# Angular2 :: EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router)

Tags: routes, angular, router

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite some hours and after searching the web for it and seeing similar working examples, I can't figure out why it's not working whatsoever.

Can't get this routing system to work: angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Some advocate the problem is the index.html and using in the header `<base href="/">` or `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>` does the trick but nope.

I have my `app.component.ts`, with the routes, as such: 
http://pastebin.com/8BrZjFEB

And the `app.component.html` as such:
http://pastebin.com/Je85pq4T

Comment: How does `bootstrap()` looks like?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Now it looks like this: http://pastebin.com/RxpCDsmM

Comment: Ok, then remove `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from all components.

Comment: Still no luck, still blowing up.